# Prepared Statement within Transaction

Tags: mysql, escaping, prepared-statement

I want to update 10000 rows in an innoDB table. Normally, it takes some minutes to finish.

The problem is an accident could occur if internet connection is suddenly interrupted. We can use Transaction for this case. For secure, I use Prepared Statement too inside Transaction but another problem appears: I can not put all 10000 rows updated in one Transaction because Prepared Statement should immediately go out of memory as we known (described [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/13/10-ways-to-crash-or-overload-mysql/) and [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,267208,267208#msg-267208)).

What should I do?

Prepared Statement is more secure, good performance but RAM consumed.
Escaping is less secure, poor performance, but all 10000 rows work successfully in one Transaction.

Comment: can't you use multiple prepared statements within a single transaction?  start the transaction, repeat the prepared statement, small chunks at a time, until all data loaded, then commit.

Comment: Thank Andrew, I tried this approach but it seems that Prepared Statement does not release memory until the whole Transaction is commited and the session is closed.

Comment: ouch :o(  what language are you using?

Comment: I use PHP back-end, Flex front-end (sorry for my English if it makes confusion).

Answer (score 0):

Use of the multiple statement with prepared statements is not supported.